# Not Able to map AJAX URL request into .java file

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, bootstrap-modal

I have created one bootstrap modal on `index.jsp`. When I click on save button I have navigated my controller from `.jsp` file to `.js` file where i have written `requestToChangePassword()` in `.js` file. Now my question is, from that function i want to make `ajax` call request so that i can enter into one of the `.java` file and proceed further.

I have written ajax call like following code is in `.js` file:

```
ajaxCallFunctionget("../view/passwordChangeRequest",data,handlePasswordChangeHandler,"text", true);
```

In java file I have written

```
@Controller
public class UserGridAjaxController {

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger( UserGridAjaxController.class.getName() );

   @RequestMapping(value = "/passwordChangeRequest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   @ResponseBody
   public String passwordChangeRequest( /*@RequestParam("userNameForEdit")String userNameForEdit,*/HttpServletResponse response )
   {
      log.debug( "In passwordChangeRequest() method of class " + getClass().getName() );
      System.out.println( "In passwordChangeRequest() method of class !!!" );
      String result = "";
      //result = delegate.deleteUser(userNameForEdit);
      return result;
   }
}
```

When I hit ajax request getting following exception in browser.

> VM230 jquery.js:4 GET 
>   http://localhost:8080/view/passwordChangeRequest?fromDate=05102019&_=1557482141385 404 (Not Found)

```
Hi I have created small project and shared proect on GitHub Please check and let me know where I am doing wrong.
```

Comment: try removing view from your url

Comment: Now error is : VM286 jquery.js:4 GET http://localhost:8080/passwordChangeRequest?fromDate=05102019&_=1557483051638 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @whererichstay I am getting VM374 jquery.js:4 GET http://localhost:8080/passwordChangeRequest?fromDate=05102019&_=1557483636827 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Please post your full controller code.

Comment: @SudhirOjha Please check my full controller code. I have edited above.

Comment: does the controller get called when you call the url without query params? eg http://localhost:8080/passwordChangeRequest

Comment: @pooja provide package name of `UserGridAjaxController ` and are you developing this using spring or spring boot.

Comment: Package name : com.analytics.controller

Comment: @Anirudh I get 404 error even when I call your mentioned URL.

Comment: Can't go any further without having a look at your entire codebase I'm afraid :)

Comment: @pooja that's not enough, please share your project structure.

Comment: Try adding `@RequestMapping("/view")` under `@Controller` annotations.

Comment: Try invokign using absolute path (so get rid of double dots) ajaxCallFunctionget("/view/passwordChangeRequest",data,handlePasswordChangeHandler,"text", true);

Comment: @SudhirOjha please check on gitHub I have created small project and shared on Git.I don't know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Link - https://github.com/praphullajadhav/ajax/